# Hitboxes creation strategies && in-isometric phaser implementation

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework, isometric

I have been playing around with phaser and its isometric plugin for the last couple of days. I am stuck in a problem and can't find a solution. I am trying to create hitboxes for my player character that take depth in account (like it should be in an isometric game):

[image: isometric hitbox]      [image: "Normal" hitbox]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htecks.gif) has depth while [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5M6Gs.jpg) doesn't. I believe that in an isometric world the depth is essential so having [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htecks.gif) is the way to go. Well that is where the problem starts. I was able to create "normal" 2d hitboxes but I wasn't able to make isometric hitboxes. My **strategy** for making hitboxes goes as follows:

- Create an hitboxes group;
- Add the individual hitboxes to that group (hitbox for head, hitbox for torso, hitbox for punch, ...);
- Add the hitboxes group to the player as a child of that player;
- Create a function that allows me to enable hitboxes when needed and check for collision;
- Create a function that allows me to disable hitboxes when I no longer need them;
- Take in account that  those hitboxes are just empty sprites (iso or non-iso depending on the type of hitbox), sprites that have no image but that can have a physics body to check for collision; they are of course "invisible".

I am not aware of other methods for making hitboxes (in phaser at least). The method should work for both isometric and non-isometric hitboxes.

---

**As for my specific situation in phaser:**

I am making my hitboxes follow the player because I am adding them as a child of that player. That way they get a fixed position to the player. Works fine for the 2d hitboxes but **I am not able to make my isometric hitboxes fixed to the player when they isometric hitboxes**. I believe this is because of something missing in the isometric plugin that doesn't correctly add a isometric sprite to another isometric sprite as a child / parent relation. I had already discussed this in here:  http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/25092-phaser-create-hitboxes-in-isometric.

The player with the hitboxes in both situations:

[image: 2d hitbox in character]
[image: isometric hitbox in character]

In [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYGWym.png) I have a 2d hitbox that is fixed to the player as it should be. In [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8Jim.png) the hitbox doesn't get fixed to the player.

The code for situation [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYGWym.png):

```
    hitboxes = game.add.group();
    hitboxes.enableBody = true;  
    hitbox1 = hitboxes.create(-100,-30,null); // I believe "create" only works with non-iso
    hitbox1.body.setSize(65,70,0,-30);
    dude.addChild(hitboxes);
```

As for the code for the [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8Jim.png) situation:

```
    hitboxes = game.add.group();
    hitboxes.enableBody = true;
    hitboxes.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Plugin.Isometric.ISOARCADE; // need to say that the physics applied is the isometric 
    hitbox1 = game.add.isoSprite(0,0,0,null,0,hitboxes);
    hitbox1.body.allowGravity = false;
    hitbox1.body.setSize(100,100,100,0,0,0);
    dude.addChild(hitboxes);
```

Some observations:

- The methods in situation [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8Jim.png) have more parameters that are for the "Z" axis;
- If I didn't set gravity to false in the [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8Jim.png) situation the body would just go through the ground. I didn't have to set anything like that in situation [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYGWym.png) because the hitbox didn't fall at all (it was fixed...);

As this didn't clearly work well I also tried setting the hitbox position in x,y and z, using (hitbox.x,hitbox.y,hitbox.z) equal to the player position (player.x,player.y,player.z) in the update function. It should somehow simulate what parent / child relation is for. It didn't work however...

As I said before I don't know another way of doing this in phaser. I would like to get this solved somehow. If you need more information please ask. Sorry for any mistakes and thank you for your attention.

EDIT:

I didn't find a perfect solution but I was able to create a function that checks for intersection between two rects. However when I "attack" and the target is above the player it still detects as collision. Probably need to to care of depth sorting or something like that...

Comment: From your edit, is this question moot now, and should be closed (or your solution posted as an answer), or did you want to update your question to ask a different one?

Comment: @JamesSkemp well my solution is a little bit nasty. I wouldn't say it is "the solution" but since there are not any better answers...

Answer (score 0):

i've created a phaser Js based library for dealing with hitboxes ( creating them and managing animations and actions for sprites with hitboxes ).

It may help you. First get the /tool folder at : https://github.com/Shadoworker/LaliaSprite

and follow this steps :

STEP 1. Run Locally (server) the project in /tool folder You can use wamp | xamp | mamp

.Two files are generated : yoursprite.png (in /sprites folder) and yoursprite.json (in /json folder)

STEP 2 . Create your new PhaserJS game project a. Write this in your index.html

```
//Load phaser.js (first)
<script src="js/phaser.js"></script>
//Load laliasprite.js*/
<script src="js/laliasprite-2.0.js"></script>
//NB : in laliasprite.js ,comment "box.alpha = 0;" to see hitboxes for debug
```

b. In your preload function , do this :

```
 //Create new Lalia instance

 Lalia = new Lalia();

//Load sprite atlases or spritesheet 

//1 . load atlases
 Lalia.atlas(game, "yoursprite", 'img/yoursprite_atlas.png', 'json/yoursprite_atlas.json', 'json/yoursprite_atlas_hitboxes.json' );

//2 . load sheet
//Lalia.sheet(game, "yoursprite", 'img/yoursprite_sheet.png', 'json/yoursprite_sheet_hitboxes.json', 180, 240);
```

c. In your create function , do this

```
//Add sprite to game scene
yoursprite = game.add.sprite(100, 30, 'yoursprite');

//Add animation to sprite
yoursprite.animations.add("idle", ["1" ,"2", "3"],1, false);

//Setting yoursprite hitboxes for a specific animation (frames);
 Lalia.atlasboxes(yoursprite, 'idle');
//Lalia.sheetboxes(yoursprite, 'idle');
...
//Add other characters 
enemy = game.add.sprite(130, 40, 'enemy');
...
//Set objects which will collide with our character (yoursprite) hitboxes 
yourspriteColliders.push(enemy);
//yourspriteColliders is the array you will declare in your code to store colliders
...
```

d. Create your action callback

```
//Do this when yoursprite is touched at a certain point during "idle" animation
  function die()
  {
     //Kill yoursprite
  }
```

e. In your update function, do this :

```
//On button taped or keyboard event
 yoursprite.animations.playaction('idle','hit', yourspriteColliders, die);

//This means: When yoursprite is playing 'idle' animation, when it's hitboxes that have the type 'hit' are touched by one of the objects in yourspriteColliders array then call the 'die' function to execute a specific action (To die in this example) ...
```

And that's all ! Hope this gonna help !